# Text align in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

How to place two different texts( using html tags ) in  column in a datagrid , in which one will be right aligned and the other will be left aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom itemRenderer for the column in question.  Here is an article on [itemRenderers](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html).

Answer (score 0):

To go along with Flextras answer, here's a quick example:

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{myArrayCollection}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="title">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:VBox paddingLeft="2" width="100%">
                        <mx:Label text="{myDataField1}" width="100%" />
                        <mx:Label text="{myDataField2}" textAlign="right" width="100%" />
                    </mx:VBox>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```